# checking constness using type_traits

Tags: c++, type-traits

I was working on a program recently which goes like this :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    shared_ptr<int> sp1 = make_shared<int>(5);
    shared_ptr<const int> sp2 (sp1);
    const int x = 8;

    // *sp2 = 7;   // error: assignment of read-only location 'sp2.std::shared_ptr<const int>::<anonymous>.std::__shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>::operator*<const int, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u>()'

    auto p = sp2.get();

    cout << typeid(x).name() << '\t' << typeid(*p).name() << '\n';

    cout << boolalpha;
    cout << is_const<decltype(*p)>::value << '\n' << is_same<const int, decltype(*p)>::value;

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is :-

```
i   i
false
false
```

As visible clearly, `typeid` specifies that `*p` & `x` are of same type & even using `*sp2 = 7` generates an error. Then why do `std::is_same` & `std::is_const` differ from it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running into two different issues here. First case we can see from the cppreference entry for [typeid](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) that top level const qualifiers are ignored:

> In all cases, cv-qualifiers are ignored by typeid (that is, typeid(T)==typeid(const T))

We can see from the cppreference entry for [decltype](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype), the following rules that are relevant here are:

> 1. f the argument is an unparenthesized id-expression or an unparenthesized class member access, then decltype yields the type of the entity named by this expression. [...]
> 2. If the argument is any other expression of type T, and
>
> [...]
>
> - if the value category of expression is lvalue, then decltype yields T&;
>
> [...]

So `*p` is an expression and is not a id-expression nor a class member access unlike let's say the following case:

```
const int x = 0 ;
std::cout << is_const<decltype(x)>::value << "\n" ; 
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Which would yield true since `x` is an id-expression.

So `*p` being an expression will yield `T&` since the result is an lvalue. The reference will not itself be const so `is_const` is correct, on the other hand this will return the result you desire:

```
is_const<std::remove_reference<decltype(*p)>::type>::value
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Note the use of [std::remove_reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference).

T.C. point out that [std::remove_pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer) could also be effective here:

```
is_const<std::remove_pointer<decltype(p)>::type>::value
```

Comment: nvm, confused `p`/`sp`. Though I would go for `remove_pointer<decltype(p)>` in that case (or go through `pointer_traits<decltype(p)>::element_type`, though that might be overkill - it does have the benefit of working on both plain and smart pointers).